# How do I correctly test a redux-thunk action with mocha

Tags: unit-testing, redux, mocha.js, redux-thunk

I'm having troubles stubbing out an async action for `redux-thunk`. **Mocha keeps giving me timeout**:

```
// actions.js
const fetchUserThings = userId => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([{ foo: 'bar' }]);
    }
  });
};

const displayUserThings = userThings => ({
  type: 'DISPLAY',
  userThings
});

export const loadUserThings = userId => {
  return dispatch => {
    fetchUserThings(userId)
      .then(userThings => displayUserThings(userThings));
  };
}
```

And here's my mocha test. I'm using [`redux` on version 3.3.1](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/v3.3.1/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md) and [`redux-mock-store` on version 0.0.6](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store/tree/v0.0.6).

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from './actions';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('actions', () => {
  it('creates DISPLAY after fetching', done => {
    const userId = 1;
    const userThings = [{ foo: 'bar' }];
    const expectedActions = [
      { type: 'DISPLAY', userThings }
    ];

    const store = mockStore({userThings: []}, expectedActions, done);

    store.dispatch(actions.loadUserThings(userId);
  });
});
```

What am I missing?